# Mail not send by PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I do have an error in PHPMailer. No autoload avalable. My script does not return an error, neither does the ->send method, but the mail does not get send.

Any Help?
my code:

```
    $mail = new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    ... Set all $mail properties ...
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "<br>Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;           
    }
    echo "<br><br><pre>";
    print_r($mail);
    echo "</pre>";
    die();
```

Results to following $mail dump:

```
    PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer Object
    (
[Priority] => 
[CharSet] => iso-8859-1
[ContentType] => text/html
[Encoding] => 7bit
[ErrorInfo] => 
[From] => no-reply@mysite.com
[FromName] => Zonder Slip
[Sender] => no-reply@mysite.com
[Subject] => 
[Body] => tesksten
[AltBody] => 
[Ical] => 
[MIMEBody:protected] => tesksten
 ...
```

Comment: Enable debugging. It's explained in the [README file example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example).

Comment: Are you sure it's not _sent_? Maybe actually it just isn't _received_. Those are not the same thing.

Comment: if I do send a mail with other means it gets to my mailbox

Comment: Result of debug does not show ME eny problem. What debug result should I verify?

Comment: I cannot see your debug output so I can only speculate, but perhaps it's what ADyson suggests: the SMTP server accepts the message but it isn't' delivered for whatever the reason (wrong DNS records, spam filters...). Your Return-Path address is `no-reply@mysite.com` so it seems you aren't accepting returned messages.

Comment: I do understand your concearn. But the "noreply" address is an accepted and existing email address. If I do send (by webmail) a mail from that address, I do get it, but the same message is not received from PHOMailer. The output of debug is to long to post it here.

Comment: Very strange: it seems the message IS SEND: when using a non-exixting email address, a message "undeliverable" is received in the no-reply mailbox?

Comment: Then it's most likely what's been already suggested: your SMTP server accepts the message, but it never makes it to recipient mailbox, probably because it's failing some spam check.

Comment: Finaly found... For some strange (???) reason my mail was considered as SPAM and the webmail did not show any spam folder. Disabling the "spam" filter on the webmail& IMAP server solved everything. So everybody was right: it was sent, and it arrived, but was maltreaded!